# I know about Bijakshara mantra .... But What is "Bijakshara mudra"?

Tags: rituals, mudra

I know about Bijakshara mantra . But What is "Bijakshara mudra" ? Does anyone know about it and link me to the process of how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the answer in isvar.org

[image: Bijakshara mudra]